# Reset Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, post-ban

I haven't logged into my account recently, and found today that I apparently have an automatic ban on my account. Can I get my account reset (questions, answers, reputation, etc)?

Comment: have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147081/195231

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was triggered by a question that you asked *twice* for some reason, and then deleted both copies of after they were answered. Don't do that.

Granted, it didn't help that a few jokers helpfully pointed out that your question was *an extremely common one* and then... closed it as Too Localized.

I've undeleted both questions, closed one as a duplicate of a pretty likely candidate (it *is* an extremely common problem), and merged the other one with it. This cleans up your account a bit, *and* preserves the efforts of those who tried to help you.

You should now be able to ask questions again. To avoid getting blocked in the future, *please* spend a little time searching first, and then ask your question *once* - if it gets closed for a bogus reason, bring that up here.

Comment: Heh, I thought Summer of Love was over, and we were deep into Fall of Reviews now. Must have been mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, well, part of that involves reviewing brain-dead closures.

Comment: If I get your point correctly, the situation is even worse than I thought. Is the review system even worth the noise it generates by now? Couldn't we just shut it down until we can devise a way to actually make it work? Please?

Comment: Thank you, however, when I click "Ask Question," I still see "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more." Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: this wasn't a product of the review system.

Comment: @Mooseman: sadly, you've collected a few more down-votes since I posted this answer, which put you past the threshold again.

Comment: @Shog9, I did not downvote myself, but there might be a reason for that to happen. I see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574186/464709) now so I guess I understand your point after all, but the two duplicates you merged are not marked as deleted (shouldn't merged questions be deleted?) and were heavily downvoted from the start. Maybe that's the problem, and the community did not understand that move?

Comment: My account works now! Thank you!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147081/195231