# Will upvoting again when my upvotes were somehow removed make me banned from Q&A?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes, post-ban

I've gone through the following questions:

*[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)*

*[Question on reasoning behind auto-'ban'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147079/question-on-reasoning-behind-auto-ban)*

From those posts, I learned that, when my question/answer gets too many downvotes or deleted, I'll be banned from Q&A. To lift the ban, I have to earn more reputation by creating or editing a question or answer to attract upvotes.

However, it is unclear to me that:

1. Will asking questions which are neither downvoted nor upvoted make me banned?
2. Will upvoting too many answers make me banned?
3. Will accepting answers increase my rep and then help to get unblocked? Or, will getting upvoted comments (no rep increase) help me get out of the ban?

I am asking because, a few days ago, I upvoted a few of the answers I got and later I find my upvotes are reversed. I upvoted again and then get reversed again and again. Then my account is banned.

PS: I think this site must fully disclose its banning mechanism. I never learn about it until I got banned. For downvoters: please let me know what I did wrong; it is much appreciated.

---

Ok, now I realized that upvoting has nothing to do with a *question ban* (this is the ban I got). I'll now work on my previous questions. One likely reason of getting instant voting reversal is probably the Internet/Wi-Fi/data instability.

Comment: 1) No, unless they're closed. 2) No. 3) ...actually, I don't know.

Comment: @RyanM So I cannot deleted/close my own question, even if it is not downvoted and attracted no answers?

Comment: 3) Comments are irrelevant for question bans.

Comment: Is it possible you were banned for voting irregularities? Which answers were you upvoting, your own answers using a second account? Votes getting reversed looks like the system detected voting fraud.

Comment: @Mast I was not serially voting for any accounts. I just upvoted all answers under the same question -- one single question.

Comment: @HighGPA did the voting reversals happen immediately after you voted, or did they happen at the end of the day? Reversals of serial voting happen at the end of the day, as far as I know.

Comment: @wimi Immediately. Within 10 min

Comment: @HighGPA hm that is strange (where "strange"=="something I cannot explain"). Might the question have been locked or deleted (in which case votes are not allowed)? Having a link to the question might help...

Comment: “I think this site must fully disclose its banning mechanism.” - We do;  You were warned multiple times and continued to submit questions.  A moderator can tell you, how many times, the warning was displayed to you

Comment: @Ramhound Really? I am curious to learn about where are the warnings?

Comment: @HighGPA - They were displayed each time before you asked a question, once you reached the threshold, that warrants the warning.  Since a question ban does not happen due to a handful of questions, you were shown this warning, at least more than once.

Comment: @Ramhound I asked five questions in the span of two years... five is exactly a "handful" . I am not complaining though, perhaps that SE site has a very strict rule.

Comment: One isn’t question banned after only 5 questions that were not well received by the community.  Hopefully a moderator will explain when the warning was displayed.

Comment: @Ramhound I think 5 might be enough. We had a similar problem on another SE site a while ago, where the affected user was question-banned and had not asked more than 5 negatively-received questions. It is probably related to the ratio of negatively-received questions/all questions.

Comment: Perhaps the author or a moderator can provide some additional details so wild speculation isn’t possible necessary.  5 questions (in total) shouldn’t be enough of those are the only questions the author asked.  If you asked 15 questions and 33% of your questions were not well received, that’s something entirely different.  Author never indicates what SE community it doesn’t appear to be SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two different, independent things seem to have happened here:

#### 1. You have a post ban on some Stack Exchange site

You did not provide details on which site or whether it is a question ban or an answer ban. As you can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/643262), a question or answer ban can only be removed by **improving your existing questions or answers**, such that your ratio of poor-scoring questions or answers falls below the ban threshold. Questions and answers are independent, so if you have an **answer ban**, your only option is to **improve your existing answers** and hope that they will get more upvotes and bring you above the threshold. Similarly, if you have a question ban, your best bet is **improving your existing questions**. Deleted posts count negatively towards the ban, so undeleting your deleted posts and improving them will also help.

#### 2. Your voting pattern seems to have been deemed "irregular" by the system, and thus reversed

**This is completely independent from the question or answer ban, and has no effect on it**. The system thinks you have done some [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/643262). This usually means that you voted too many times for the same user in a short time. When this is detected, the system reverses it. If this happens once, voting reversal is the only consequence. If it happens more often or becomes a pattern, it might be investigated and a timed suspension might be issued on the relevant site, which would temporarily set your reputation to 1 and block you from participation for a while. Looking at your network profile, this **does not seem to have happened in your case** (unless you are asking about a hidden/different account).

The exact thresholds for a post ban or for voting irregularities are kept secret to prevent people from "gaming the system".

So my advice to you would be to be more careful to avoid serial voting, and improve the relevant posts (questions or answers) on the relevant site to get out of the post ban.

Comment: As for point 1, if you have a question ban you get a new chance every 6 months to ask a question. Make that question count! That might be your only way to redeem yourself from a question ban.

Comment: @Luuklag there are better methods, but ofcourse

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein in some cases there are no posts to improve on an account, in that case this is the only solution

Comment: @Luuklag there is a second option. If you think you are facing targetted voting, you can ask questions anonymously(without logging in somesites), then after receiving the upvotes (1 is sufficient), you can request a merge which will be done immediately

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein that is called ban evasion, which is punishable by account deletion. So not something I would advice to do.

Comment: @Luuklag Not a ban evasion if you have not been banned. Before someone is question banned, they receive a two day suspension from posting questions. One can do it during that time

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein that is still ban evasion, the fact that you call it "suspension" instead of "ban" of course does not change anything. In any case, I do not think this is the place to discuss this...

Comment: well then asking good questions are ban evasion as well. If you didnt understand, if someone is suspended for LQ questions for two days, they have an indication that they need to get upvotes the next time they are allowed to ask. Only someone with pure urge would like to ask it during their ban (also, wouldnt a moderator notice that the account was banned?!). Second, if i remember, this answer is about post(question/answer) ban and looks like you miss this point for users who get targetted out of the site.

Comment: “Before someone is question banned, they receive a two day suspension from posting questions.” You sure that’s the case.  I have **never** heard this before.  Please provide a reliable source

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein `"well then asking good questions are ban evasion as well."` No that is not the case, as you are allowed to ask that one question every X timeinterval. That is a way for SE to give people the ability to redeem themselves. That's how the system is designed, so nothing gets evaded there.